# Can useMemo be used in an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you safely leverage `useMemo` in an anonymous function?

```js
import {useCallback, useMemo} from "react";

function Component(props) {
  const [scollLeft, setScrollLeft] = useState(0); // dictates which elements are visible on screen

  const onScroll = useCallback(({scrollLeft}) => {
    setScrollLeft(scrollLeft);
  }, [])

  const itemToElement = useCallback((item) => {
    return useMemo(() => generateElementFrom(item), [item]); // <-- anonymous useMemo !
  }, []);

  const visibleItemsOnScreen = useMemo(() => {
    return props.items.filter(item => isVisible(item));
  }, [scrollLeft, props.items]);

  const visibleElementsToRender = useMemo(() => {
    return visibleItemsOnScreen.map(x => itemToElement(x));
  }, [visibleItemsOnScreen]);

  return <>{visibleElementsToRender}</>;
}
```

Does the above reliably memoize the `elements` generated from each `item`?

Comment: "React hooks like useState and useEffect must be used at the beginning of a function component or other hook" — That's not true.

Comment: What you saying is not true, do you have any resources to those facts?

Comment: OP updated to remove these statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your example on the order of execution is a bit misleading. You must use all your hooks **without conditions**, it doesn't have to be the first lines of code in your functional component.

Regarding question, you can **not** use `useMemo` inside a callback (With or without `useCallback`)

The rule is:

```
React Hook "React.useMemo" cannot be called inside a callback.
React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function. (react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)
```

The reason is that React holds the state of each one of your components separated. and in order to "know" the state of each hook, it uses the order of execution. using hooks in conditions will mess the order of the hooks, and React wont be able to match previous state with the new state.

`useCallback` is not a React component and React won't manage it's internal hooks state, so you can't use `useMemo` inside `useCallback`